# In Inkscape, how to create a gradient between color A and color B instead of color A and transparent?

Tags: color, inkscape, gradient

I'm just getting familiar with Inkscape (v0.91), currently working on a picture which will consist of overlapping objects each containing shadow gradients, something like this:

[image]

**How I do change the gradient of the blue circle so that it transitions from blue to white (or another color) rather than blue to transparent?** I want the blue circle to be opaque.

Answer (score 7):

(Inkscape v0.92) Start Figure 1:

(Figure 2): Let's say we want that blue circle to transition from blue to yellow, but not transparent. First you select the gradient tool, then you drag your mouse over the blue circle so that a gradient handle appears. Now click on the end of the gradient handle that has just been created, which is a tiny circle. You'll see that tiny circle turns blue, which means it has been selected.

(Figure 3): Now click on some color (yellow) from the color palette down in the screen. The color of our blue circle would respond immediately:

In the end, the direction and length of the gradient can be adjusted by dragging the gradient handle, until it looks desirable.

[image]
This Youtube video provides all of the information:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39mJPLl-nno

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - after activating the Gradient Tool, click on the *node* at the end of the gradient line superimposed on the object & then choose the desired color from the toolbar at the bottom of the window. I had been fiddling around in the Fill and Stroke menu with no success.